# Asking about a specific virus when others are closed

Tags: discussion, questions, allowed-topics, scope

After searching virus questions on Super User, I've noticed that many are closed. Is this site the place to ask a question about a specific virus on a home PC running Window 7?

Specifically, I want to know how to remove Live Security Platinum.

As common as that virus is, I'm surprised I've not seen it on SU. I'd like to direct my question to the correct site, if perhaps that isn't here.

Comment: Because most of the question are similar to [this one](http://superuser.com/q/100360/86550) which is approximately fits for the other solutions. If it doesn't help you then you can take help of chat of SU and ask the users about the specified virus, I'm sure they will help you.

Comment: As they closed most of time for the dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process for removing any virus is largely the same regardless of the virus, so the general  question:

[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

will more than likely be applicable.

If you've tried the things suggested there (up to but not including reformatting your hard drive) and you've still not removed the virus you could ask another question referencing the canonical one, but you might get a better response by asking in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Of course it could be that the only solution is to reformat your hard drive....